# How to upgrade to “Mono v3” on openSuse 12.2

Tags: opensuse, mono

I have mono 2.10.9 installed on a VM with openSuse version 12.2. I'm trying to find a distribution for the latest v3 Release of Mono which I can use to upgrade the version of mono that I have installed. I cannot find any distribution of Mono 3 for openSuse and I'm wondering how to go about upgrading to Mono 3 (if it's possible).

Please note I come from mainly a Windows background and while I have used Unix in the past (SCO Unix), the Unix world has changed a lot since I last was involved with it. I'm sure I can get mono to build on openSuse, but it's the number of other dependencies that are required, their versions etc; and I'm just not comfortable enough with the environment yet to get a grip on it all.

I hope that someone out there can point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Mono:Factory project in OBS](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=Mono%3AFactory) - it's not considered stable yet. You can also get there from the [opensuse package directory](http://software.opensuse.org/package/mono-core) - click "select other versions" then "show unstable versions".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've managed to download and install mono-complete, just need to figure out where it got installed to now.

Comment: `rpm -ql mono-core` gives you list of installed files. You can also check this in the yast-packager of course.